# nginx 404 when i use known file extensions in url

Tags: nginx

Whenever I put a known file extension in the url nginx return `404 Not Found`.

`domain.com/myroute.foo` and `domain.com/foo/myroute.foo` is fine, but `domain.com/myroute.php` and `domain.com/foo/myroute.php` (or for example .css, .js)  returns `404 Not Found`.

My nginx server config:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     domain.com;
        root            /var/www/path/public;

        charset utf-8;
        gzip on;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
                index index.html index.php index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files                       $uri = 404;
                fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index   index.php;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
                include         fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
                add_header        Cache-Control public;
                add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
                expires           7d;
                access_log off;
        }
}
```

Why isn't a url with a known file extension (`/myroute.php`) going to my `index.php` file like any other url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`myroute.php` does not exist on your server.

Nginx `location` directives are checked in this order

> 1. Directives with the "=" prefix that match the query exactly (literal string). If found, searching stops.
> 2. All remaining directives with conventional strings. If this match used the "^~" prefix, searching stops.
> 3. Regular expressions, in the order they are defined in the configuration file.
> 4. If #3 yielded a match, that result is used. Otherwise, the match from #2 is used

That means that your `myroute.php` request gets handled by the `~ \.php$` location block, which results in a 404 as per your try_files directive.

To solve this, you'll need to either make your location directive more specific (e.g. `~ index\.php$`), or try_files exactly as you do in the `location /`. Using a rewrite could also solve your issue.

EDIT:

It is important to understand in what order nginx chooses location blocks over other location blocks. See more at the [nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)

Regarding your question, the easiest solution I think is to use try_files

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

in both your `location ~ \.php$ {` and `location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {` blocks

- Note: don't forget to remove your old `try_files $uri =404` from the `.php$` block

Your final conf file should now look like this

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     domain.com;
    root            /var/www/path/public;

    charset utf-8;
    gzip on;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
            index index.html index.php index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|ico|pdf|flv|swf|exe|html|htm|txt|css|js) {
            try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            add_header        Cache-Control public;
            add_header        Cache-Control must-revalidate;
            expires           7d;
            access_log off;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That worked for `/myroute.php`, but other extensions like `/myroute.css` or `/myroute.js` still returns 404.

Comment: Yes, I only wrote about the php rule to make my point. The same applies for the css and js files. I'll edit my answer